# Is it possible to find the k-largest numbers from n unsorted integers with time complexity O(n) and space complexity O(k)?

Tags: algorithm

I know that we can find the k-largest numbers from n unsorted integers in 2 ways:

1. Use an algorithm like quick-select to find the Kth largest number, then we can get the k-largest numbers. The time complexity is O(n) and space complexity is O(n)
2. Use a heap to store the k-largest numbers and iterate through n integers, then add proper integers to the heap. The time complexity is O(nlogk) and space complexity is O(k)

Suppose the n integers are in a stream and we don't have random access to them

I want to know is it possible to find the k-largest numbers from n unsorted integers with time complexity O(n) and space complexity O(k)?

Comment: Why do you consider the quick select to have space complexity O(N). It has O(1) addition memory complexity(assuming you can re-arrange the input)

Comment: It is doable. See http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0015429 By using this algorithm, you can find the k-th largest number in linear time with only constant number of additional variables.

Answer (score 5):

It is. After filling the heap with k elements, instead of evicting one element from the heap after every insertion, evict k elements from the heap after every k insertions. Then you don't need the heap structure any more -- just select every time.

Comment: This sounds nice. It seems to me you don't actually need a heap, just an array with 2k positions.

Answer (score -1):

k passes of bubble sort will give k largest elements at last of the array timeo(nk)